# difference between paypal invoice createInvoice and CreateAndSendInvoice?

Tags: paypal

I will integrating paypal invoice in my website. I found two type invoice generation 1)CreateInvoice 2)CreateAndSendInvoice. Explain difference between paypal invoice createInvoice and CreateAndSendInvoice and which one is better ?

Comment: thanks for giving suggestion.I will integrate paypal invoice php api into my website.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/invoicing/IntroInvoiceAPI/#creating-and-sending-invoices)

CreateAndSendInvoice - **Creates** and **sends** an invoice, which is equivalent to the combination of the **CreateInvoice** operation followed by the **SendInvoice** operation.

neither is better, but the latter does the former AND sendInvoice in one step.